# Finding the closest value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
X     A    B   C    D 
10  10.2  16   28  30 
20  27    15   14  16
30  30.4  34   35  45
```

i want to create a new column which shows values from A,B,C or D in case they are 2% close to 'X'.

Intended Result:

```
X     A    B   C    D   result
10  10.2  16   28  30   10.2
20  27    15   14  16   NaN
30  30.4  34   35  45   30.4
```

I can identify values that are close to "X" with the following code but now sure how to bring out values from A,B,C,D columns:

```
cond = np.isclose(df.X, df['A'], rtol=0.02) | np.isclose(df.X, df['B'], rtol=0.02) | np.isclose(df.X, df['C'], rtol=0.02) | np.isclose(df.X, df['D'], rtol=0.02)

df['result'] = np.where(cond,#See note,np.nan)
```

#note: how do I put column value that meets the criteria?

Little help will be appreciated. THANKS!

Edit:

```
ID  OP     X   Vl  Ch  A    B   C    D   result
          10           10.2  16   28  30   10.2
          20           27    15   14  16   NaN
          30           30.4  34   35  45   30.4
```

Blank values have some data in them. ID is string, others are float.

Comment: Can there be more than one value that satisfies the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val = [[10,  10.2,  16,   28,  30], [20, 27,  15,  14, 16], [30, 30.4,  34,  35, 45]]
df = pd.DataFrame(val, columns=list('XABCD'))

# split df for convenience:
target_X = df['X']
df2 = df.drop('X', axis=1)
tol = 0.02

# get the closest value to X within the tolerance tol:
df['Result'] = df2[df2.subtract(target_X, axis=0).abs().apply(lambda x: x <= target_X * tol)].min(1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. It gives out an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float' . My actual dataset is formatted a little different (check the edit). Probably that is causing the error, little help pls. Thanks

Comment: No problem, just declare df2 in this way `df2 = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]`, instead of `df2 = df.drop('X', axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 10.2, 16, 28, 30], [20, 27, 15, 14, 16], [30, 30.4, 34, 25, 35]], columns=["X", "A", "B", "C", "D"])

In [2]: def f(x):
     ...:     # If there are multiple values that meet the conditions, please modify here
     ...:     c = None  # []
     ...:     for i in x[1:]:
     ...:         if i/x[0] >=1.0 and i/x[0] <=1.02:
     ...:             c = i
     ...:             break
     ...:             # c.append(i)
     ...:     return c
     ...:

In [3]: df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis=1)

In [4]: df
Out[5]:
    X     A   B   C   D  result
0  10  10.2  16  28  30    10.2
1  20  27.0  15  14  16     NaN
2  30  30.4  34  25  35    30.4
```

Comment: Hey, it gives out an error. My actual data is formatted a little different, check the edit pls. Thanks

Comment: if i/x[0] >=1.0 and i/x[0] <=1.02:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Please set the type of column. ``df.X = df.X.astype(float)`` (X, A, B, C, D)